# QMake Uses Wrong Directory For 32 Bit Build

Tags: c++, qt, 32bit-64bit, qmake

All I am attempting to compile a 32 bit build on a 64 bit 13.04 ubuntu.

I have installed the correct multiarch g++ libs and the ia32-libs package. I can see the `.so`'s I need in `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu` and `/lib32/`

My approach so far:

```
export QMAKESPEC=linux-g++-32
qmake myproject.pro
make
```

I have noticed that I am compiled with the `-m32` flag, however when it comes to link time, I see `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`. This is not being set from any of the `.pro` files, I confirmed with a quick

```
grep -r 'x86_64-linux-gnu' <src>
```

I feel like I'm missing a flag somewhere, or maybe it's using the wrong g++ and I need to adjust the link? I can't find any information on this.

---

Link call:

```
g++ -m32 -Wl,-O1 -o output [redacted.o] -L/[some_lib_dir] -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lQtCore -lpthread
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to switch to Ubuntu 32 bit. I determined the problem is that qmake does not let you set the link directories for its core plugin libraries.

Other people interested in researching look into:

```
qmake -query
qmake -set QT_INSTALL_PATH
```

That seems to be the link directory being used, but I was unable to specify my own unqiue directory.